# Writing type definition files

Tags: typescript, type-definition

I am following along with a course that seems to be outdated (at least that is what it looks like to me). I need to write a type definition file (own implementation) for lodash (this is to show how type definition files are written).

The code that is given is:

```
declare module "lodash" {

  declare interface FirstFunction {
    (data: any[]): any;
  }

  declare interface Lodash {

    first: FirstFunction;

  }

  export const _: Lodash;

}
```

However this does not seem to work anymore as it throws the error: "A 'declare' modifier cannot be used in an already ambient context". Fixing this as follows by removing the nested declarations gives the following file:

```
declare module "lodash" {

  interface FirstFunction {
    (data: any[]): any;
  }

  interface Lodash {

    first: FirstFunction;

  }

  export const _: Lodash;

}
```

If I now try to use it (call the first function) the compiler throws an error: "error TS2339: Property 'first' does not exist on type 'typeof import("lodash")".

The .ts file that imports lodash is:

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';

const colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];

const firstColor = _.first(colors);

console.log(firstColor);
```

At this point I started looking at the typescript manual and read they do this differently. Using the way they did in their example seems to fix all the error. Meaning writing the type definition file a follows works:

```
declare module "lodash" {

  export function first(data: any[]): any;

}
```

My question now is, is it no longer possible in an interface, to describe the input and output for a function, so it's signature is reusable?

Comment: Wild guess - try lodash.Lodash.first

Comment: ... That did not solve it but it pointed me in the right direction. The way the example was written exports an interface under the name _. This means to call the first function you should call it like _._.first(). I presume the course I am following must be really outdated as I can not imagine this is a correct way to write a type definition file these day's.